# Django-haystack filter by ForeignKey->DateTimeField

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm trying to filter my search results by start date. The start date however is stored as a ForeignKey object's field.

### Models

```
class Observation(models.Model):
    taxon_node = models.ForeignKey(TaxonNode)
    sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample)
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timespan_begin = models.DateTimeField()
```

### SearchIndex

```
class ObservationIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    taxon_node = indexes.CharField(model_attr='taxon_node')
    sample_timespan_begin = indexes.CharField(model_attr='sample__timespan_begin')
```

### Form

```
class ObservationSearchForm(SearchForm):
    start_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(ObservationSearchForm, self).search()

        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        if self.cleaned_data['start_date']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(sample_timespan_begin__gte=self.cleaned_data['start_date'])

        return sqs
```

### Index

```
{{ object.taxon_node }}
{{ object.sample.timespan_begin }}
{{ object.remarks }}
```

I can't figure out where the problem is. sqs doesn't change after applying the filter. Is there something wrong with my observation_text or is the sqs.filter() invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed version of sqs =

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(sample_timespan_begin__gte=self.cleaned_data['start_date'])
```